# input/read through termimal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Let's say i want to run a bash script, is there a command in the terminal to specifiy the values that my script would ask for instead of using read?

for example at the time that i type bash script1.sh can i somehow type values to pass to the script or does it first have to be executed.

Like bash script1.sh 3 4

Comment: not asking about time, i'm asking if when i run my bash script can i provide values on the same line that the bash script would need or does it first have to run and then i can provide values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access command line arguments of a bash script you use the `$@` array, and also the `$0`, `$1`, ..., `$N` values.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "First argument is $1"
echo "Second argument is $2"
```